# "Crucial to cell division is/are the alignment and segregation"

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number, verb-agreement

I'm in the process of writing a research paper for school. Looking back at the introduction of my original research proposal (which I'm using as a scaffold for my current paper) I realized that the use of "is" vs. "are" in one sentence might not be right, but I don't know how to deconstruct the sentence to figure it out:

> Crucial to successful cell division **is** the alignment and subsequent segregation of chromosomes into daughter cells…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have a *subsequent* in the sentence, you should use *is*. Without the *subsequent*, you would use *are*. But the phrase *"alignment and subsequent segregation"* treats the whole process as a single entity, like *fish and chips* or *macaroni and cheese*.

From Google books:

> According to this approach, phosphate precipitation and subsequent removal from wastewater is mediated by microbial activity in the aeration tank of the activated sludge process.
>
> Though by midsummer, when the fall in prices it had predicted had not materialised, the Society recanted of its pessimism, and declared that a stock market fall and subsequent depression was not on the cards ...